# Why Not Hyperthermia?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

I know it's a word, but I'm having trouble finding it in any sense. I've only going words like

> heat stroke,  overheat

But never the technical opposite of hypothermia. Why is that, or is that an uncommon, but in use word?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hyperthermia%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: One good reason for avoiding ***hyperthermia*** in *spoken* contexts is that it's not easy to articulate or discern the difference between that and the somewhat more common ***hypothermia***. And since non-technical people are more likely to know the latter, that's what they'll tend to hear. For problems relating to ***high*** body temperature, they're more likely to use terms such as ***fever, sunstroke, heatstroke***.

Comment: Those terms describe symptoms of "hyperthermia", but the word itself only means the body temperature is too high. You do hear usage of "hypothermia" but more often common symptom words like shivering, frostbite or gangrene.